# ERROR in using beautiful Soup to extract SEC filling header information with returning NONE

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

When I'm trying to use beautiful soup to get the header information from the SEC I'm getting a a return value of none. The tag I'm using is `"<SEC-HEADER>"`.

Any idea on how to get this code work correctly?

My code is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# URL of the SEC filing
url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1166036/000110465904027382/0001104659-04-027382.txt'

# Fetch the SEC filing data
response = requests.get(url)
content = response.content

# Parse the content with Beautiful Soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')

# Find the SEC-HEADER tag using a custom function
def find_sec_header(tag):
    return tag.name == 'sec-header'
sec_header = soup.find(find_sec_header)

# Extract the header data
if sec_header:
    header_data = sec_header.get_text()
    print(header_data)
else:
    print("SEC-HEADER not found in the document.")
```

From the website link in the ode you can see their is header information. Copy of some of the text is:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVACY-ENHANCED MESSAGE-----
Proc-Type: 2001,MIC-CLEAR
Originator-Name: webmaster@www.sec.gov
Originator-Key-Asymmetric:
 MFgwCgYEVQgBAQICAf8DSgAwRwJAW2sNKK9AVtBzYZmr6aGjlWyK3XmZv3dTINen
 TWSM7vrzLADbmYQaionwg5sDW3P6oaM5D3tdezXMm7z1T+B+twIDAQAB
MIC-Info: RSA-MD5,RSA,
 Qv2jQwkNcHK0jmh1uw9JmsapJjhSCceQJLdEQsrmZh5YPKB2tMIC07tAARLtOJNv
 RF+yO70MOHHbXjXQABtM/g==

<SEC-DOCUMENT>0001104659-04-027382.txt : 20040913
<SEC-HEADER>0001104659-04-027382.hdr.sgml : 20040913
<ACCEPTANCE-DATETIME>20040913074905
ACCESSION NUMBER:       0001104659-04-027382
CONFORMED SUBMISSION TYPE:  8-K/A
PUBLIC DOCUMENT COUNT:      7
CONFORMED PERIOD OF REPORT: 20040730
ITEM INFORMATION:       Completion of Acquisition or Disposition of Assets
ITEM INFORMATION:       Financial Statements and Exhibits
FILED AS OF DATE:       20040913
DATE AS OF CHANGE:      20040913

FILER:

    COMPANY DATA:   
        COMPANY CONFORMED NAME:         MARKWEST ENERGY PARTNERS L P
        CENTRAL INDEX KEY:          0001166036
        STANDARD INDUSTRIAL CLASSIFICATION: CRUDE PETROLEUM & NATURAL GAS [1311]
        IRS NUMBER:             270005456
        FISCAL YEAR END:            1231

    FILING VALUES:
        FORM TYPE:      8-K/A
        SEC ACT:        1934 Act
        SEC FILE NUMBER:    001-31239
        FILM NUMBER:        041026639

    BUSINESS ADDRESS:   
        STREET 1:       155 INVERNESS DR WEST
        STREET 2:       STE 200
        CITY:           ENGLEWOOD
        STATE:          CO
        ZIP:            80112
        BUSINESS PHONE:     303-925-9275

    MAIL ADDRESS:   
        STREET 1:       155 INVERNESS DR WEST
        STREET 2:       STE 200
        CITY:           ENGLEWOOD
        STATE:          CO
        ZIP:            80112
</SEC-HEADER>
<DOCUMENT>
<TYPE>8-K/A
<SEQUENCE>1
<FILENAME>a04-10341_18ka.htm
<DESCRIPTION>8-K/A
<TEXT>
<html>

<head>



</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `User-Agent` HTTP header to obtain the correct response from the server:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1166036/000110465904027382/0001104659-04-027382.txt'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/112.0'}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

def find_sec_header(tag):
    return tag.name == 'sec-header'

sec_header = soup.find(find_sec_header)
print(sec_header.text)
```

Prints:

```
0001104659-04-027382.hdr.sgml : 20040913
20040913074905
ACCESSION NUMBER:               0001104659-04-027382
CONFORMED SUBMISSION TYPE:      8-K/A
PUBLIC DOCUMENT COUNT:          7
CONFORMED PERIOD OF REPORT:     20040730
ITEM INFORMATION:               Completion of Acquisition or Disposition of Assets
ITEM INFORMATION:               Financial Statements and Exhibits
FILED AS OF DATE:               20040913
DATE AS OF CHANGE:              20040913

FILER:

        COMPANY DATA:
                COMPANY CONFORMED NAME:                 MARKWEST ENERGY PARTNERS L P
                CENTRAL INDEX KEY:                      0001166036
                STANDARD INDUSTRIAL CLASSIFICATION:     CRUDE PETROLEUM & NATURAL GAS [1311]
                IRS NUMBER:                             270005456
                FISCAL YEAR END:                        1231

        FILING VALUES:
                FORM TYPE:              8-K/A
                SEC ACT:                1934 Act
                SEC FILE NUMBER:        001-31239
                FILM NUMBER:            041026639

        BUSINESS ADDRESS:
                STREET 1:               155 INVERNESS DR WEST
                STREET 2:               STE 200
                CITY:                   ENGLEWOOD
                STATE:                  CO
                ZIP:                    80112
                BUSINESS PHONE:         303-925-9275

        MAIL ADDRESS:
                STREET 1:               155 INVERNESS DR WEST
                STREET 2:               STE 200
                CITY:                   ENGLEWOOD
                STATE:                  CO
                ZIP:                    80112
```